# In SlickGrid, how do I collapse grouping via javascript

Tags: grouping, slickgrid

I want to apply grouping in SlickGrid. I want collapse them via javascript.

This is my script http://pastebin.com/MbXgQ22Y  (Dead link)

```
dataView.collapseGroup(0);
collapseAllGroups();
```

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 line of code to collapse them which is: `dataView.collapseAllGroups()` Make sure that your version of SlickGrid is not too old as this function of collapsing all was implemented last month...

Comment: What happen with my question? and the link isn't dead. i still can open. @ghiscoding would u help me (again) to give me a very simple demo for implementing grouping (and collapsing). maybe you have a blog which contain slickgrid tutorial. thanks in advance

Comment: i replace with newer slick.dataview.js and it's work. thanks. i really need more tutorials.

Comment: Your link was never dead for me... You should replace the complete SlickGrid not just 1 file. As for documentation, unfortunately there isn't much as we all have a job but any questions you have will be answered as long as it fits stackoverflow format for being constructive. On the grouping side, I know it much more since I worked on the core code for expandng the grouping to multi-columns functionality.