# SlickGrid CollapseAllGroups

Tags: jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I am trying to get dataView.collapseAllGroups() to work with SlickGrid.

The post [In SlickGrid, how do I collapse grouping via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920700/in-slickgrid-how-do-i-collapse-grouping-via-javascript) says to just use collapseAllGroups() but it doesn't seem to work.

Even when going to the current demo page http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html and typing dataView.collapseAllGroups() into the console, it doesn't seem to do anything.  Is there something else that I need to do to refresh the grid?

**Edit**

I was trying to get the Grid to display a tree where the groups are collapsed by default.  Although I cannot get CollapseAllGroups() to work, I was able to do a hack by adding "if (item._collapsed == null) item._collapsed = true;" to myFilter function that is in the example above.

This is a rough worksound but it does the job for now until I find the real solution:

```
function myFilter(item) {

    // Added this line:
    if (item._collapsed == null) item._collapsed = true;

    if (item.parent != null) {
        var parent = gridData[item.parent];
        while (parent) {
            if (parent._collapsed) {
                return false;
            }
            parent = gridData[parent.parent];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular example demonstrates how to implement hierarchies using custom formatters and a filter.  It does NOT use the DataView's grouping feature, so the `collapseAllGroups()` call has no effect.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I ended up doing something like people were doing here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slickgrid/4ado2RxZsG8